# Does java really support rectangular arrays? If not what are non-jagged arrays called in java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example,
`int[][] numbers=new int[3][5];`
is clearly not a jagged array.
Can it be called a rectangular array?

Answer (score 6):

A rectangular 2-dimensional array is just a special case of a jagged array. Therefore, any language that supports jagged arrays will also support rectangular arrays, while the inverse is not necessarily true.

The expression `int[][] numbers = new int[3][5];` is just syntactic sugar, and actually boils down to something like:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
numbers[0] = new int[5];
numbers[1] = new int[5];
numbers[2] = new int[5];
```

Nothing prevents you from turning a rectangular array into a jagged array after declaration:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[3][5];
numbers[0] = new int[10]; // works
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) says:

> In computer science, a **ragged array**, also known as a **jagged array**, is an array of arrays of which the member arrays can be of different sizes and producing rows of jagged edges when visualized as output. In contrast, two-dimensional arrays are always rectangular so jagged arrays should not be confused with multidimensional arrays, but the former is often used to emulate the latter.

According to that, a jagged array is not a 2D array, i.e. the term 2D implies rectangular.

Your question was: *What are non-jagged arrays called in java?*
Answer: **A two-dimensional array**.

Or more precisely "a multidimensional array", since non-jagged is not limited to only 2 dimensions.